# Adding element with the splice method

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, addition, splice

I am trying to Us the javascript splice method to add a "-" before every capital latter in my array but it is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code below.

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  let strArr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    strArr.push(str[i]);
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
    if(strArr[i] !== strArr[i].toLowerCase()){
      strArr.splice(strArr.indexOf(strArr[i]),0, "-");
    }
  } 
console.log(strArr);
}

spinalCase('thisIsSpinalTap');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new element with `splice` you're increasing the `length` of the array and the loop is never able to finish. If you work the loop from the end of the array to the beginning instead you can avoid this problem.

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  let strArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    strArr.push(str[i]);
  }

  // Work the loop from the end to the beginning
  for (let i = strArr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if (strArr[i] !== strArr[i].toLowerCase()) {
      strArr.splice(strArr.indexOf(strArr[i]), 0, "-");
    }
  }
  console.log(strArr.join(''));
}

spinalCase('thisIsSpinalTap');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you wanted to use splice, but here is a little regex solution; just in case.

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
 return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, "-$&").toLowerCase();
}

console.log(spinalCase("thisIsSpinalTap"))
// this-is-spinal-tap
```

Answer (score 0):

You changed your array when you do:

```
strArr.splice(strArr.indexOf(strArr[i]),0, "-");
```

So `strArr.length` is not constant for the loop `for(let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++)`